# AngleSharp parsing to valid HTML <script> and XML

Tags: anglesharp

I'm writing a parser for sites using AngleSharp, I need to eventually get XML.

When parsing in xml, there are problems with parsing the section script, because there are such symbols "<% =" "%>".
Errors occur on the rows that are numbered

How can I solve this situation (I need to use AngleSharp)? I tried with different sites, the result is the same

```
        var config = Configuration.Default
                      .WithCss()
                      .WithDefaultLoader();
        var address = Url.Create("https://www.google.com/");
        var document = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        var xDocument = new HtmlParser().Parse(document.DocumentElement.InnerHtml);
        var formatter = new AngleSharp.Xml.XmlMarkupFormatter();
        var result = xDocument.ToHtml(formatter);
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(result); //1

        var parserXML = new XmlParser().Parse(document.DocumentElement.InnerHtml);//2
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(parserXML.ToHtml());
```

Answer (score 1):

XML is incompatible to HTML even though they same very similar. So in general this is not possible, however, when you define how to handle the differences you could come up with a result that may be acceptable.

At the core of such a conversion the following function needs to be defined. We only take care of 4 Node types - there shouldn't be any others appearing. For simplicity we discard any namespaced elements or attributes.

```cs
static XmlNode CreateNodeFrom(XmlDocument document, INode source)
{
    switch (source.NodeType)
    {
        case NodeType.Comment:
            return document.CreateComment(source.TextContent);
        case NodeType.Element:
            var original = (IElement)source;
            var element = document.CreateElement(original.LocalName);

            foreach (var attr in original.Attributes)
            {
                element.SetAttribute(attr.Name, attr.Value);
            }

            return element;
        case NodeType.Text:
            return document.CreateTextNode(source.TextContent);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

The function will almost exclusively used from the tree converter:

```cs
static void AppendChildren(INode source, XmlNode target)
{
    var owner = target.OwnerDocument;

    foreach (var child in source.ChildNodes)
    {
        var node = CreateNodeFrom(owner, child);
        target.AppendChild(node);
        AppendChildren(child, node);
    }
}
```

So we just walk the tree and convert what we see... Changing your original function:

```cs
var config = Configuration.Default.WithCss().WithDefaultLoader();
var address = Url.Create("https://www.google.com/");
var document = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address).Result;
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
var root = CreateNodeFrom(xmlDocument, document.DocumentElement);
xmlDocument.AppendChild(root);
AppendChildren(document.DocumentElement, root);
```

(I don't know why you used all these different parsers; parsers work on text level, but HTML and XML are incompatible on text level - so let's try to convert on a DOM level, which is where we can control what is happening).

I removed some redundancy and improved your async->sync bridge (but I would encourage you to remove the `.Result` and use `await`, i.e., returning a `Task<XmlDocument>` instead of a `XmlDocument`).

Hope this helps!